# MacBookPro Core i7 - system profiler says "Number of cores: 2"

Tags: macbook-pro, multi-core, intel-core-i7, quad-core

I thought that "quad core" meant quad core. My system says that it has 2 cores, but perhaps I'm thinking of it wrong, or perhaps the OS ignores 2 cores. What do you know about the issue.

(Note: Intel isn't shipping the new dual core i5 / i7s until the 20th, so if mine actually is a "dual core", I'm gonna be mad).

Profiler output:

```
Model Name: MacBook Pro
  Model Identifier: MacBookPro6,2
  Processor Name:   Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed:  2.66 GHz
  Number Of Processors: 1
  Total Number Of Cores:    2
  L2 Cache (per core):  256 KB
  L3 Cache: 4 MB
  Memory:   4 GB
  Processor Interconnect Speed: 4.8 GT/s
  Boot ROM Version: MBP61.0057.B0C
  SMC Version (system): 1.58f16
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the [Intel i7 M620](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=43560) with 2 cores. [Mactracker](http://www.mactracker.ca/) confirms CPU model (i7 M620) for your device.

[Apple](http://www.apple.com/macbookpro/specs.html) doesn't advertise number of cores in tech specs, but the store clearly says:
[image]

Intel didn't offer models with 2+ GHz and 4 cores until 2011.

Comment: +1 for you. And that is why I bought the i5 quad core iMac.

Comment: What he said.  The only models that offer >= 4 cores from Apple are the high end iMac and the Mac Pro (as of this writing).